# How to convert spaced number with comma fraction delimeter in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Currently looking into way to convert number like:

```
 699 937,57
```

Into

```
  699937.57
```

I'm looking into something like

```
SELECT to_number(column, 'FM99G999G999') from mytable;
```

But the last example will drop decimal numbers

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to simply replace the comma with a dot and then convert that result to a number:

```
select to_number(replace(the_column, ',', '.'), 'FM999999.99')
from mytable
```

This however requires you to know the maximum number of digits before the decimal point. Another option would be to remove all whitespace from the string (after replacing the comma) and then cast that to a number:

```
select regexp_replace(replace(the_column, ',', '.'), '\s+', '', 'g')::numeric
from mytable;
```

Regular expressions are somewhat expensive, to the second solution is probably slower (but more robust) then the first one.

The following:

```
with mytable (the_column) as (
  values ('699 937,57'), ('123,45'), ('456,789'), ('123 456 789,1234')
)
select regexp_replace(replace(the_column, ',', '.'), '\s+', '', 'g')::numeric
from mytable;
```

returns:

```
regexp_replace
--------------
     699937.57
        123.45
       456.789
123456789.1234
```